# Powershell- how to copy all files by extension type to the same folder?

Tags: powershell, file, recursion, copy

I'm trying to iterate on an existing powershell script I have. The script I have requires all files I'm parsing through to be in the same folder. The issue, is the files are originally in different folders by machine name, and then nested in another folder from there.
For example: /parent/hostname001/result/hostname001.xml , /parent/hostname002/result/hostname002.xml , etc.

What would be the most efficient way to do this- basically a "cp /parent/*/result/*.xml /outputdirectory/" type function, to explain simply.
Appreciate the help!

Attempted a few things - using https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/copy-item?view=powershell-7.4 seemed like the best shot but I was getting an error when trying to use wildcards. I'm not at work at the moment so unfortunately don't have specifics.

Answer (score 0):

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-7.4

You can do this with `Get-ChildItem` using the `-Filter` and `-Recurse` parameters, quick one liner.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Source" -Recurse -Filter *.xml | Copy-Item -Destination "C:\Destination"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use wildcards in a `Get-ChildItem` search for files, so something like this:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path ".\Parent\*\result\*.xml" | Copy-Item -Destination .\OutputDirectory
```

That would get *all* XML files in the result folder for each host, but you could filter that in a `Where-Object` if needed.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path ".\Parent\*\result\*.xml" | Where-Object {$_.basename -eq $_.Directory.Parent.Name} | Copy-Item -Destination .\OutputDirectory
```

That would make sure the file name (excluding extension) would be the same as the folder 2 levels up.